# Multiple Views for UITabBarController

Tags: view, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to build an app where I have a TabBarController with 4 entries.
When I select the first entry, a view with a UITableView shows up.
This TableView is filled with several entries.

What I would like to do is:
When an entry out of that UITableView gets selected, another view should show up; a detailview.

.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (indexPath.row == 0) {

if(self.secondView == nil) {
SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
self.secondView = secondViewController;
[secondViewController release];
}

// Setup the animation
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.secondView animated:YES];

}
}
```

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SecondViewController.h"


@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

SecondViewController *secondView;

NSMutableArray *myData; 
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) SecondViewController *secondView;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readwrite) NSMutableArray* myData;

@end
```

This is what I have so far.

Unfortunately.. the code runs, bit the second view does not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your first view controller wrapped in a `UINavigationController`?  When you set up your `UITabBarController`, you should add UINavigationControllers rather than your UIViewController subclasses, e.g.:

```
FirstViewController *viewControl1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navControl1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewControl1];
UITabBarController *tabControl = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
tabControl.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navControl1, <etc>, nil];
//release everything except tabControl
```

Also, based on your code, you don't need to keep your secondViewController as an ivar, since UINavigationController automatically retains its view controllers (and retaining it when you're not displaying it will use up unnecessary memory).